# In VLBI astronomy measurements, does one measure the same photon using both instruments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, astronomy, interferometry

Most professional astonomy (that I heard of) at visible or radio frequencies is done with instruments that try to collect EM waves such that signals stay coherent.

But I wonder why the light from distant stars would be coherent. The photons we detect will often be generated completely independently on the source, and have no coherency.

So I wondered whether the coherency comes from the photons themselves? If for instance hubble or Webb sees a photon from a distant star, the emitted photon is spread out in space (across the entire mirror or larger), but then focused with the parabolic mirror and thus detected.

For a single dish this does not sound too outlandish to be true. It is typically not stated out loud if this is or is not the process.

Does this reasoning also apply to VLBI, meaning that the signal coherency in VLBI is due to the same photon being joint detected by two instruments, and if so does it require realtime combining of signals?

Thanks in advance for any answer. I don't mind a bit of reading so I'd be happy with a link if this topic is covered somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

VLBI is not a quantum technique. Classical measurements of amplitude and phase are recorded at the antenna sites. They are combined later in classical (not quantum) computers. From a physics point of view, the interference is a digital simulation, not physical interference.